# Link between a categorical and an algebraic characterization of (infinite-dimensional) Hilbert space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ct.category-theory, hilbert-spaces

On one side, a very recent paper of Chris Heunen and Andre Kornell "Axioms for the category of Hilbert spaces" ([Arxiv:2109.7418v1](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.07418v1) [latest Arxiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.07418)) offers a characterization of the category of (real and complex) Hilbert spaces using only six purely categorical axioms.
On another side a well-known theorem of Maria Soler gives a purely algebraic characterization concerning the infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces on the star division rings of the real or complex numbers or quaternions.
I would like to know if anyone sees a way to build a relation between these two results.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. I didn't know Sol`er’s Theorem before. Here is a link to a survey: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9504224.pdf. the new paper you mention (link: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2109.07418.pdf) uses this theorem in their proposition 5. This is how they get the concrete field $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ out of the rather abstract categorical setting. So in a concrete sense, there is a relation between these two results...

Comment: I find this question very superficial, considering that Soler's result is the main ingredient in the proof of Heunen and Kornell, as a short look at the paper teaches.